# SonarQube/ SonarCloud - Is there an option in SonarQube Web Interface (UI) to display analysis per commit basis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

Is there an option in SonarQube Web Interface (UI) to display analysis on per commit basis? Currently it has option to display branch level only. It's hard to pin point on which commit the bug was introduced.

I'm using :

- SCM Type - `github` and `gitlab`
- Sonarqube - `sonarCloud` or `6.7.5`

I want to be able to see something as shown below. Is this even possible?

```
Master
|
|-branch/branchName1  - 8 Bugs, 2k Code Smells, 1 vulnerability
  |-9asdfhjsalfhlsahfdlsdfsala (commit sha) - 8 Bugs, 2k Code Smells, 2 vulnerability
  |-1asfjksajfkjsakljsakjlsajl (commit sha) - 0 bugs, 0 code smells, 0 vulnerabilities
|-branch/brachName2 - 0 Bugs, 0 Code Smells, 0 Vulnerability
. . .
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could see analysis per commit, is if you actually perform an analysis per commit.

However, there's another feature that should be suitable to your use case.
On the **Code** tab, when SCM blame information was available at the time of anaysis, SonarQube will show you who changed each line of code. Take for example this issue on line 37, it was part of a change starting on line 34, done by "dani...".

[image: example issue]

Now, if you click on the username who made the change, in this case "dani...",
then a window pops up with the date and the commit ID. There, that's the sha1 that touched this piece of code.

[image: commit sha of change]